# process.env.PORT is Undefined. Problem occurring in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, dotenv, .env

I am new to typescript.

Imported and used dotenv package but still getting undefined
It is necessary to declare interface for the dotenv variables?

```js
import express,{Application} from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import  dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const app : Application = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

console.log(process.env.PORT);   //undefined

app.listen(3000, ()=>console.log(`server started on 

http://localhost:${3000}`));
```

.env File

```
PORT = 3000
SECRET=SOME_SECRET
```

package.json

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
}
```

Comment: You get undefined in console? Or type of it is undefined?

Comment: yes i am getting undefined in console..

Comment: It is not typescript problem. Make sure your .env file and your executable are at the same level in the file tree. Isn't it?

Comment: I defined .env file in src folder.

Comment: Did you already test the answers of all those other [process.env undefined](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=node+process.env+undefined+site%3Astackoverflow.com) questions?

Comment: Have you tried removing the extraneous whitespace on either side of the `=` in the first line of your `.env` file?

Comment: @Digen And your server.js(or index.js or smth else.js) file in src folder too?

Comment: @vbykovsky yes my .evn file and index.js are in the src folder

Comment: And where is you console opened, when you starting your application? In the root of project?

Comment: Try to move .env file to root directory

Comment: Okay I Got the problem. I Defined it inside the src folder. So I removed it from the src. Now I am getting the output. Thank You Guys. And thank you @vbykovsky

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare interfaces for environment variables in Typescript. Where's your .env file located relative to the Typescript file you pasted?

The .env file should be at the project's root, in the same directory as the project's `package.json` file. If it's located somewhere that's not the root or that `dotenv` can't figure out, I'd recommend using the following example for configuring dotenv:

```js
dotenv.config( { path: '../relative/path/.env' });
```